# string.indexof() function in {{if}} construct of jsviews

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I've been using [jsviews](http://www.jsviews.com/) to link and render some templates. In one of my template, I have the following `{{if}}` condition.

```
<script id="listTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">    
  {{if content_type.indexof('IMG_') >= 0 }}
    <span class="content-img-preview" data-src={{:distURL}}></span>
  {{else}}
    ''
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Where content_type is a string that can can be like 'IMG_201_345'.
However, the `indexof()` function does not work. How else can I check if the string contains the pattern 'IMG_' using the  `{{if}}` condition?

Comment: Yeah you're right!! indexOf() did the trick.
That was a really silly mistake from my side!!

Comment: Some frameworks can hide exceptions without logging, looks like jsviews authors' mistake to prevent developers to find bugs.

Comment: Yeah...but then, jsviews is still in alpha, maybe they'll fix it :)

Comment: JsViews will render out "Error: Object IMG_201_345 has no method 'indexof'." - which helps developers to find bugs. But you can set $.views.settings.debugMode(false) and it will hide the error information. Choose debugMode(true) - the default - while you are developing, and debugMode(false) for production. What error behavior were you looking for/expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use `indexof` my code return:

> Error: Object IMG_201_345 has no method 'indexof'.

by using `indexOf` is working fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/MG3nL/

Answer (score 1):

On line

```
{{if content_type.indexof('IMG_') >= 0 }}
```

function name should be changed to correct in this way:

```
{{if content_type.indexOf('IMG_') >= 0 }}
```